# Is there a way to see the internal representation of float?

Tags: python, floating-point

In [python tutorial for floating point](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html),

> In base 2, 1/10 is the infinitely repeating fraction
>
> 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...

How do I get python interpreter to print this intenal representation? `repr(0.1)` does not help.

Comment: You can get a hex representation like this `(.1).hex()`

Comment: The binary numeral for 1/10 is not the internal representation for the `float` value. Do you want to see the binary numeral or the bits that encode the value in the floating-point format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the struct module to get the internal representation of float. Once you get the representation, you just need to convert the character to the ordinal value and format it to binary.

```
>>> import struct
>>> def float_rep(num):
    return ''.join("{:08b}".format(ord(elem)) for elem in struct.pack('!f', num))

>>> float_rep(0.1)
'00111101110011001100110011001101'
```

**Edit**

Though the above would provide you the actual representation internally, but I suppose, you are more interested in  the binary equivalent of the decimal. The following would suffice your query

```
>>> def float_to_bin(num):
    sign = '-' if  num < 0 else ''
    num = abs(num)
    whole = int(num)
    num  -= whole
    yield sign + bin(whole) + '.'
    while num:
        num*= 2
        whole = int(num)
        yield str(whole)
        num -= whole


>>> ''.join(islice(float_to_bin(1.1),None,20))
'1.0001100110011001100'
>>> ''.join(islice(float_to_bin(-1.1),None,20))
'-1.0001100110011001100'
>>> ''.join(islice(float_to_bin(.1),None,20))
'0.0001100110011001100'
>>> ''.join(islice(float_to_bin(0),None,20))
'0.'
>>> ''.join(islice(float_to_bin(1),None,20))
'1.'
>>> ''.join(islice(float_to_bin(0.25),None,20))
'0.01'
>>> ''.join(islice(float_to_bin(0.5),None,20))
'0.1'
>>> ''.join(islice(float_to_bin(-0.5),None,20))
'-0.1'
```

Comment: I guess you have sign, mantissa and exponent all mixed up together here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Can you please explain your comment? This is the internal representation of float

Comment: I don't think Jichao actually wants the internal representation of the float. I think he wants `1/10` written in base 2: `0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: So the question is ill formed. In any case, I have added an update.