# How to get the exact memory representation of fp16,fp32,bf16,int8,... and so on in python?

Tags: python, floating-point

Is there any function that can give me the exact representation (as it is stored in memory) of a number ? What I am looking for is a function with the following behaviour:

memory_repr(3,'int8') = oooooo11

memory_repr(3,'fp16') = 01000000010000000000000000000000

Basically, I want a python api to do what https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html does, that works with any data type

I tried math.frexp comes close but not quite it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638975/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-internal-representation-of-float

Comment: Another related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421466/how-to-print-out-the-memory-contents-of-object-in-python

Comment: How a value is stored in memory is an implementation detail, not something that Python itself mandates.

Comment: Try bin(id((3, 'fp16')))  you can use it to create a generalized function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import struct

def memory_repr(number, data_type):
    if data_type == 'int8':
        packed = struct.pack('b', number)  
    elif data_type == 'uint8':
        packed = struct.pack('B', number) 
    elif data_type == 'fp32':
        packed = struct.pack('f', number)  
    elif data_type == 'fp16':
        packed = struct.pack('e', number)  
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported data type")
    packed = struct.pack('>' + format_char, number)
    return ''.join(f'{byte:08b}' for byte in packed)

print(memory_repr(3, 'int8'))  
print(memory_repr(3, 'uint8'))  
print(memory_repr(3.0, 'fp16')) 
print(memory_repr(3.0, 'fp32'))
```

Output :

```
00000011
00000011
0100001000000000
01000000010000000000000000000000
```

Here I am not sure about bf16.

Corrected for float as rightfully highlighted

Comment: Except that you've messed up the byte order.   3.0 as a single is 0x40400000, not 0x00004040.  You can deal with that by adding '>' to the `struct.pack` call.

Comment: @TimRoberts please check now made changes as per your suggestion. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Your modification is only half completed.  You need to replace the `struct.pack` calls with `format_char='b'` etc.